# Sending many transactions from one address in quick succession?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, transactions-per-second

I was wondering if anyone has figured out an effective way of sending many different transactions in quick succession from the same address? I have an application that can require making 100+ transactions a minute. So far the only solid way I've been able to facilitate this is to use about 50 different addresses, since I have to wait for one transaction to confirm before I can send another one (with CLI and Cardano REST API). I think this occurs because the UTXOs don't update until confirmation, which affects the next transaction attempt. Does anyone know of a more efficient way of sending many transactions in quick succession using CLI, the Cardano Wallet REST API, or even the Cardano Serialization Library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the application you are building, but it's possible you could include all the actions in a single transaction.

You can use arbitrarily large amounts of constraints on your transaction in off-chain wallet code for smart contracts. [Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/5ffcfa6c0451b3b937c4b69d2575cd55adebe88b/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Uniswap/OffChain.hs#L213) is an example with 4 constraints, but you could do as many as you needed to get your job done. I believe you would need to wait until the PAB (Plutus Application Backend) is operational before you can use that wallet code on the mainnet, however.